# NullPointerException when writing to AudioTrack instance in a callback from native code

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I perform some decoding process in the native code and call a Java method from it to write samples into the AudioTrack instance. Decoding process runs fine, the callback from native code to Java:

```
private void writeToAudioTrack(final byte[] buffer)
```

is called , but once the Runnable object starts to write samples into the AudioTrack I get a NullPointerException immediately. I am quite sure it is caused by wrong threading, but cannot figure out what is wrong there. I am attaching the complete Java code:

```
public class Player
{
    private AudioTrack track;
    private boolean isInitialized = false;
    private static Handler handler = new Handler();

    public void init(String mediaSource)
    {
        // Call native function initEngine
        isInitialized = initEngine(mediaSource);

        if (isInitialized)
        {
            int bufSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            track.play();
        }
    }

    public void play()
    {
        // Call native rendering function in a separate thread
        if (isInitialized)
        {
            new Thread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    renderAudio();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public void release()
    {
        isInitialized = false;
        releaseEngine();
    }

    // This is callback from native code
    private void writeToAudioTrack(final byte[] buffer)
    {
        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    track.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // 
    static
    {
        // Load native library
        System.loadLibrary("decoder");
    }

    // Private native methods
    private static native boolean initEngine(String mediaSource);
    private static native void releaseEngine();
    private static native void renderAudio();
```

Even if I create a buffer in place of try-catch block:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[256];
track.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

I get the same result - NullPointerException.

**Stack Trace:**

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mautilus.audioplayer.Player$2.run(Player.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: maybe track is not initialized? where do you initialize it if isInitialized is false?

Comment: are you calling `releaseEngine` too early? could you show player usage?

Comment: Please show us the exception stack trace, in particular,  which line of your code the exception comes from (not just a line number)

Comment: Track is initialized `track.getState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING` and `releaseEngine` is not called at all. Stack trace added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the type of one of the native methods - `initEngine`, it must not be declared as static - in this case.

According to the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16660

The `GetMethodID()` causes an uninitialized class to be initialized. So if the library loading is not tied with any class instance (that's normal):

```
static
{
    // Load native library
    System.loadLibrary("decoder");
}
```

then the native code:

```
jmethodID writeToAudioTrackMethodID = NULL;
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com.mautilus.audioplayer.Player");

if (!cls)
writeToAudioTrackMethodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "writeToAudioTrack", "([B)V");
```

called from a static method - `initEngine` in my case, can't obtain any existing instance of the class (even if such instance exists) and creates new one (with fields initialized to default values) - that's it...

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

To add some more protection, I'd add a:

```
if (!isInitialized) {
   return;
}
```

to the front of the `writeToAudioTrack` method to make sure that the callback is not being called when `isInitialized` is `false`.  How is the callback registered?  Can you show that code?

---

Maybe a stupid answer but in your constructor, are you sure it should not be:

```
if (!isInitialized) {
    ...
}
```

If not then are you *sure* that the `run()` method is not being called if `isInitialized` was returned as `false` from the call to `initEngine`?  If this is the case then `track` would be null which would explain the NPE in the `run()` method.

An easy way to figure this out would be to put an `assert` in the `run()`:

```
assertNotNull(trace);
```

or do a proper test and throw an `IllegalStateException` if `trace` is `null`.

The only other thing that could cause the NPE is if a `null` value for `buffer` was passed into the `writeToAudioTrack` method.  Testing for `null` there and throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` might be a good idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Actually, this check is unnecessary, if the engine doesn't initialize there is no writing to AudioTrack...

Comment: I don't see how `writeToAudioTrack` is called @vitakot.  Is it possible for that method to be called by the callback even if isInitialized is false?

Comment: Either `trace` or `buffer` is null dude.  I'd add some protection to see if that gives you more information.

Comment: Thank for your effort, voted up. I will definitely add some error handling in the production version, but I needed it working at least under "ideal" circumstances. I found a bug and posted my answer.